# asp.net core Trouble adding a startup extension to startup.cs

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am missing something here. I have been following [this github](https://github.com/codeprefect/multitenancy/tree/develop/src/Multitenant) project and in it the author specifically adds and extension static method:

```
public static class StartupExtension
{
    public static void EnsureMigrationsRun(this IApplicationBuilder app, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var dbContextFactory = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IDbContextFactory>();
            var allTenants = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ITenantProvider>().AllTenants;
            foreach (var tenant in allTenants)
            {
                var context = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(tenant, configuration);
                context.Database.Migrate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In his startup.cs he has added it (last item) to the configure method as so:

```
       app.EnsureMigrationsRun(Configuration);
```

So I considered doing a similar thing - adding a method to the end of my configure method.

```
    public static void EnsureMigrationsAndInitialisationRun(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var dbContextFactory = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IDbContextFactory>();
            var allTenantConnectionStrings = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISessionServices>().AllTenantConnectionStrings();

            foreach (var tenantConnectionString in allTenantConnectionStrings)
            {
                var context = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(tenantConnectionString);
                context.Database.Migrate();
                // Add in the initializations here.
            }
        }
    }
```

In the project I am looking at, its clear his method is available to add (checked intellisense) however in my startup.cs I have no option of adding this or any other method other than the ones supplied as standard.

I added it nevertheless:

```
        app.EnsureMigrationsAndInitialisationRun();
```

and got the following error.

> Error CS1061  'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for
>   'EnsureMigrationsAndInitialisationRun' and no accessible extension
>   method 'EnsureMigrationsAndInitialisationRun' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I had intended to add a few items to app... including a session middleware but that is not showing up either.

How do I add methods likes session middleware and this case initialisation method to the configure method?

Why dont these static methods show up?

EDIT..

I was able to add a middleware by the directive `app.UseMiddleware<ConfigureSessionMiddleware>();`

However I still dont know what I need to do to add an initialisation file onto the end of the app pipeline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the keyword `this` in your extension method which doesn't make it an extension method.

If you do it like this inside a static class (mandantory as well) it works just fine

```
    public static void EnsureMigrationsAndInitialisationRun(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var dbContextFactory = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IDbContextFactory>();
            var allTenantConnectionStrings = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISessionServices>().AllTenantConnectionStrings();

            foreach (var tenantConnectionString in allTenantConnectionStrings)
            {
                var context = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(tenantConnectionString);
                context.Database.Migrate();
                // Add in the initializations here.
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you can call

```
app.EnsureMigrationsAndInitialisationRun();
```

in your `Configure` method.